# InStr in If Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I need to loop through all the worksheets in my workbook.  If the name of the worksheet contains the text "Benefits" then I need to run a macro on that worksheet as the active worksheet and then loop to the next.

I have this code and (1) it runs the macro either way and (2) it doesn't loop to the next sheet.

I'm new to VBA and haven't been able to figure this out.

```
Sub CheckSheets()
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(sh.Name, "Benefits") <> 0 Then
            Call AddCheckBoxesRange
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub


Sub AddCheckBoxesRange()
'by Dave Peterson
'add Form checkboxes
Dim c As Range
Dim myCBX As CheckBox
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rngCB As Range
Dim strCap As String

Set wks = ActiveSheet
Set rngCB = wks.Range("B3:E3")
'Set rngCB = Selection
strCap = "Select Plan"

For Each c In rngCB
  With c
    Set myCBX = wks.CheckBoxes.Add _
      (Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, _
       Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
  End With
  With myCBX
    .Name = "cbx_" & c.Address(0, 0)
    .LinkedCell = c.Offset(1, 0) _
        .Address(external:=True)
    .Caption = strCap
'    .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name _
'        & "!mycbxMacro"
  End With
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Change your If statement to be `If InStr(1, sh.Name, "Benefits", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` and it's hard to say if you need any other adjustments without seeing the code for `AddCheckBoxesRange`

Comment: How does `AddCheckBoxesRange` know which sheet to operate on?

Comment: Short answer:  add `sh.Activate` before the `Call`. Boring but correct answer: modify your `AddCheckBoxesRange` to have its target sheet in parameter instead of acting on the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: I change the if statement and it still runs the macro on whatever the active sheet is and doesn't loop.  I added the code for the other macro in my original post.  I found this on line (credit shown in code) and made modifications as needed.

Comment: @A.S.H I added the "short answer" and it works perfectly.  I don't know how to do it the "correct" way.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the `Activate` (always a good thing to avoid), your code should look like:

```
Sub CheckSheets()
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    'Use the Worksheets object instead of the Sheets object
    ' so that we don't try to process any Charts
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(sh.Name, "Benefits") <> 0 Then
            'Pass the sh worksheet, and avoid the old Call syntax
            AddCheckBoxesRange sh
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub

'Change the subroutine to accept a Worksheet as a parameter
Sub AddCheckBoxesRange(wks As Worksheet)
    'by Dave Peterson
    'add Form checkboxes
    Dim c As Range
    Dim myCBX As CheckBox
    'Don't need to declare wks anymore as it is declared as a parameter
    'Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rngCB As Range
    Dim strCap As String

    'Don't need to set wks anymore as it is passed as a parameter
    'Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Set rngCB = wks.Range("B3:E3")
    'Set rngCB = Selection
    strCap = "Select Plan"

    For Each c In rngCB
      With c
        Set myCBX = wks.CheckBoxes.Add _
          (Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, _
           Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
      End With
      With myCBX
        .Name = "cbx_" & c.Address(0, 0)
        .LinkedCell = c.Offset(1, 0) _
            .Address(external:=True)
        .Caption = strCap
    '    .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name _
    '        & "!mycbxMacro"
      End With
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Sub CheckSheets()
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name Like "*benefits*" Then
            Call AddCheckBoxesRange(sh.Name)
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub


Sub AddCheckBoxesRange(sName)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sName).Activate
    'by Dave Peterson
    'add Form checkboxes
     Dim c As Range
     Dim myCBX As CheckBox
     Dim wks As Worksheet
     Dim rngCB As Range
     Dim strCap As String

     Set wks = ActiveSheet
     Set rngCB = wks.Range("B3:E3")
    'Set rngCB = Selection
     strCap = "Select Plan"

     For Each c In rngCB
         With c
             Set myCBX = wks.CheckBoxes.Add _
                 (Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, _
                 Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
         End With
         With myCBX
             .Name = "cbx_" & c.Address(0, 0)
             .LinkedCell = c.Offset(1, 0) _
             .Address(external:=True)
             .Caption = strCap
             '.OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name _
             ' & "!mycbxMacro"
         End With
     Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works and I'm guessing from @A.S.H. 's post that this is the correct way, not the short way.  Both worked.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JordanCA57 yes that's what I meant, Always better to avoid counting on the `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell` and `Selection` stuff. :)

Comment: @RyanL I think it's even better to pass the worksheet directly as function parameter instead of the name.

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H, I didn't realize that would be faster.

Comment: I wish I knew even half of what you guys do!!  I'm going to print out this entire post and see if I can figure out some of what your talking about.  For now I'll use the example given.  Thanks for the help and also how quickly you respond.

Answer (score 3):

Some minor adjustments to the good answer you have already received:

1. No need to activate worksheets in the second sub, better to work with the sheet directly
2. Pass the sheet itself to the main sub rather than the sheet name
3. You were checking for *Benefits* not *benefits* so good to use `Lcase$` to make sure you are capturing your string
4. Use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to turn off Excel when it is manipulating the environment (although not selecting the sheets will get rid of most of the screen flashing in this case).

*calling sub*

```
Sub CheckSheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If LCase$(sh.Name) Like "*benefits*" Then Call AddCheckBoxesRange(sh)
    Next sh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

*main sub*

```
Sub AddCheckBoxesRange(ws As Worksheet)

    'by Dave Peterson
    'add Form checkboxes
     Dim c As Range
     Dim myCBX As CheckBox
     Dim rngCB As Range
     Dim strCap As String


     Set rngCB = ws.Range("B3:E3")
    'Set rngCB = Selection
     strCap = "Select Plan"

     For Each c In rngCB
         With c
             Set myCBX = ws.CheckBoxes.Add _
                 (Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, _
                 Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
         End With
         With myCBX
             .Name = "cbx_" & c.Address(0, 0)
             .LinkedCell = c.Offset(1, 0) _
             .Address(external:=True)
             .Caption = strCap
         End With
     Next c
End Sub
```